# Adding Gestures on a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've found ways to add gestures to a view, buttons, but nothing on this :(

This is what i'm trying to do. *tap* on the plus button to add a tag. but *tap and hold* the same plus button to bring up an action sheet to either add a tag group or a tag. And the problem is giving the gesture to the UIBarButtonItem.

This is how i initialize my buttons:

```
[self.navigationItem setPrompt: @"Tags"];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem: [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target: self action: @selector( pressedNavRight:)] animated: YES];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem: [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target: self action: @selector( pressedNavLeft:)] animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIView *buttonItemView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 30)];
buttonItemView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGes = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
[buttonItemView addGestureRecognizer:tapGes];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGes = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressAction:)];
[buttonItemView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGes];
UIBarButtonItem *barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonItemView];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barItem;
```

Comment: add gestures to a custom view. And initialize the barButtonItem with the view.

Comment: getting there, sadly when i tried the long tap, the UITapGestureRecognizer was called as well, after the UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

Comment: this does not happen on my simulator. can you show me what you have done in tap action and long press action?

Comment: tap action i have a display of an alert view and in the long action a display of an action sheet. once the action sheet is dismissed the alert view of the tap action shows up

Comment: looks like that problem is gone, i hope. but now the long tap is called more than once per long tap. like the long at action is called twice vs just once like you'd expect

Comment: just add this `if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {//do something}`

Comment: awesome! looks fixed, i added `if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)` bc `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` would be called once the user lifts their finger and i perfered to have the use tap and hold then the action shows up and then the user lifts their finger. thanks for your support :)

Comment: any tips on making the view look like the add button, `UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd`?

Comment: If the custom view is set, the style property can't work. So add an image to the view.

Comment: therefore i will have to simulate a button, image for highlighted and normal states, huh